# Error en Kubernetes usando Minikube, instalando el paquete de wordpress con Helm

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes

alguien sabe la razón por la cuál me podría estar saliendo este error?

Get https://192.168.49.2:8443/version?timeout=32s: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "minikubeCA")

Intento usar este comando: helm install my-wordpress bitnami/wordpress --version 19.4.1, y me sale el error que está arriba.
He reiniciado varias veces el cluster, y actualizado permisos y aún no me funciona.
De antemano les agradezco.